# Does the order of nested quantifiers matter for $\exists x \forall y P(x) \vee Q(y)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I fail to see difference between $\exists x \forall y P(x) \vee Q(y)$ and $\forall y\exists x  P(x) \vee Q(y)$.
after all, there is no relation between x & y, and all we need to do is to check if one of the statements is true for the overall statement to be true since the or relation $\vee$.

like,
for every $x$ there is at least a $y$ that makes the statement $P(x) \vee Q(y)$ true

for every $y$ there is at least an $x$ that makes the statement $P(x) \vee Q(y)$ true.

Comment: Do you mean $\exists x\forall y[P(x)\lor Q(y)]$? Because the way you wrote it, without brackets, it means $[\exists x\forall yP(x)]\lor Q(y)$.

Comment: @bof In some textbooks quantifiers scope as far to the right as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(x)$ has a single value that makes it true,  both statements are true due to the fact that it is an or.

If $P(x)$ is a contradiction,  then the truth value of the or reduces to $Q(y)$, so it will only be true if $Q$ is a tautology.  So yes, they are equivalent in this case.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that more generally, though $\forall y \ \exists x \ P(x, y)$ and $\exists x \ \forall y \ P(x, y)$ are not in general the same, though. For instance, if $P(x, y)$,  is $x^2 = y$ and the universe of discourse is the positive reals. This first says that every positive real $y$ has an $x$ such that $x^2=y$, which is true, while the second says that there is a positive real $x$ that is the square root of every positive real $y$, which is false.

Comment: @CadeReinberger Yep,  I had to pause and work out this particular case to confirm that it worked here :).

Answer (score 1):

Working with the formulae as given:

- $$\exists x \forall y P(x) \vee Q(y)$$ is first-order equivalent to
  $$\exists x P(x) \vee Q(y),$$ which is first-order equivalent to
  $$\forall y\exists x  P(x) \vee Q(y).$$

Working with the given formulae but with brackets inserted (in case they had accidentally been omitted):

- $$\exists x \forall y [P(x) \vee Q(y)]$$ is first-order equivalent to
  $$\exists x [P(x) \vee \forall y Q(y)],$$ which is first-order
  equivalent to $$\exists x P(x) \vee \exists x \forall y Q(y),$$ which
  is first-order equivalent to $$\exists x P(x) \vee \forall y Q(y),$$ which is first-order equivalent to $$\forall y [\exists x P(x) \vee Q(y)],$$ which is first-order equivalent to $$\forall y [\exists x P(x) \vee \exists x Q(y)],$$ which is first-order equivalent to $$\forall y \exists x [P(x) \vee Q(y)].$$

---

Similarly, these two sentences *happen* to be first-order equivalent:

1. $$\exists x \forall y [P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)]$$
2. $$\forall y \exists x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)].$$